# Isolate composer php packages in vendor to parent folder

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I want to create multiple plugins in wordpress and I want each of these plugins have their own composer.json and vendor folder.

But I want to Isolate each of it from other classes in other plugin vendor folder.

I want to do this beacuse each of these plugins may depends on different version of a package.

Directory structure eaxmple:

```
--plugins
  --plugin1
    --vendor
      --package A v1.0.0
      --package B v1.0.0
  --plugin2
    --vendor
      --package A v1.2.0
      --package C v1.0.0
  --plugin3
    --vendor
      --package A v1.4.0
      --package D v1.0.0
  --plugin4
    --vendor
      --package A v1.7.0
      --package E v1.0.0
```

So How can I do this and isolate each plugin from others?

Comment: You cannot do that with composer. Only one version of `package A` can be installed.

Comment: Hello @rob006,
Yes thanks, that's the answer I was looking for